# How to close linux terminal with python script

Tags: python, linux, terminal

Just wondering if there's a way to close the terminal with a python script in an if else statement. I know how to exit a program with "exit( 0 )" but is there a way to actually close the terminal, like when you hit "X" or Alt + F4?

Thanks! (I'm new to python so I don't know much, sorry.)

Comment: Close the terminal that python is running in or a separate terminal?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34389409/2873538)?