# Is there a python code to completely exit the termux terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, termux

before this only exits the script at hand and not the whole terminal. I tried:

```
import os
os.system('exit')
```

and that only exits the script. Any Idea how i exit the whole terminal?

Comment: Is this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389322/how-to-exit-linux-terminal-using-python-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes
if you want to exit python type `exit()` if you want to exit terminal type `exit`

Answer (score 0):

Use only `exit` in the script. It will be enough to exit the terminal like the above command you have mentioned.